# Maximum Number string datatype in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table is here

[image]

My SQL query

```
SELECT isnull(Max(CardNo),'0-0') FROM PRCCoatingData Where PRCNO='N001AHH'
```

But output was

```
N001AHH-9
```

I have get max no 10 but only 9 showing. How it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to treat parts of an identifier differently (say, by having part of it treated as a number), it's a good idea to store those parts in *separate columns* where appropriate data types can be used. Don't confuse *what needs to be shown/presented to users* with *what data you need to store*.

Comment: `'9'` *is* larger than `'10'` though; those are **strings** *not* numbers.

Comment: `CardNo` should be an integer data type and just have `1`, `9`, `10` etc. You can then do the concatenation of `PRCNO`, `'-'`, and `CardNo`  to derive the current format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to handle this. First the sample data:

```
create table proccoatingdata (
    prcno  VARCHAR(255),
    Cardno VARCHAR(255));
GO

INSERT     dbo.proccoatingdata
SELECT     f.X, CONCAT(f.X,'-',n.N)
FROM       (VALUES ('ABC123'),('XXXYYYZZZ')) AS f(X)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS n(N)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.proccoatingdata;
```

This gives us:

```
prcno           Cardno
--------------- -----------------
ABC123          ABC123-1
ABC123          ABC123-2
...
ABC123          ABC123-9
ABC123          ABC123-10
XXXYYYZZZ       XXXYYYZZZ-1
XXXYYYZZZ       XXXYYYZZZ-2
...
XXXYYYZZZ       XXXYYYZZZ-9
XXXYYYZZZ       XXXYYYZZZ-10
```

Note that I included a couple different prcno values in case that is what you are dealing with. The solution would be:

```
SELECT      TOP(1) WITH TIES p.prcno, p.Cardno
FROM        dbo.proccoatingdata AS p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST(SUBSTRING(p.Cardno,
             CHARINDEX('-',p.Cardno)+1,200) AS INT))) AS f(SortKey)
ORDER BY    f.SortKey DESC;
```

This returns:

```
prcno        Cardno
------------ ------------------
XXXYYYZZZ    XXXYYYZZZ-10
ABC123       ABC123-10
```

For better performance you can also create in indexed view. This provides the same benefits of the computed column but without the need to make changes to your existing table.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.idxView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT      p.Cardno, p.prcno, SortKey = CAST(SUBSTRING(p.Cardno,
                                           CHARINDEX('-',p.Cardno)+1,200) AS INT)
FROM        dbo.proccoatingdata AS p;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idxVw ON dbo.idxView(sortkey,cardno);
GO
```

You can then query the indexed view like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES v.*
FROM     dbo.idxView AS v
ORDER BY v.SortKey DESC;
```

Again, correct answer ***but*** this time with a sort free execution plan.

BOOM.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed column:

```
create table proccoatingdata (
    prcno varchar(255),
    _cardno int,
    prcnocardno as (concat(prcno, _cardno))
);
```

Then you can simply use `_cardno` for ordering:

```
SELECT TOP (1) CardNo
FROM PRCCoatingData 
WHERE PRCNO = 'N001AHH'
ORDER BY _CardNo DESC;
```